# Split a vector into sub vectors with constant length and constant overlap

Tags: r, split

I want to split a vector into a set of subvectors such that these conditions hold:

1. all subvectors must have a constant length
2. all subvectors must overlap with a constant overlapping length

I need a modification to this:

```
########Block function######################
blocks <- function(len, ov, n) {

  starts <- unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, len), seq(len-ov+1, n, len))))
  ends <- pmin(starts + len - 1, n)

  # truncate starts and ends to the first num elements
  num <- match(n, ends)
  head(data.frame(starts, ends), num)
}

########Moving block#############
vec = 1:17 # a list or vector
len = 8 # the length of the subvector 
ov = ceiling(len/2) # the length of overlap
b <- blocks(len, ov, length(vec))
with(b, Map(function(i, j) vec[i:j], starts, ends))
```

**that produces this:**

> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 # subvector 1

> [2] 5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 # subvector 2

> [3] 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 # subvector 3

> [4] 13 14 15 16 17 # subvector 4: overlap needs modification to achieve constant length

**What I want**

I want the last subvector that doesn't reach the specified length to have an overlap like this:

`new_overlap = old_overlap + (old_length - new_length)`

- new_overlap is the length of overlap of the last subvector that its length is less than the set length.
- old_overlap is the set length of overlap
- old_length is the set length of subvector

> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 # my desired subvector 1

> [2]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 # my desired subvector 2

> [3]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 # my desired subvector 3

> [4] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 # my desired subvector 4

I want a list to be split with the following conditions:

- It should have the same sublist length.
- It should overlap with a constant

**Attempted Solution with an error message but nice result**

```
blocks <- function(len, ov, n) {

  starts <- unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, len), seq(len-ov+1, n, len))))
  ends <- pmin(starts + len - 1, n)

  # truncate starts and ends to the first num elements
  num <- match(n, ends)
  head(data.frame(starts, ends), num)
}

########Moving block#############
vec = 1:10 # vector
len = 5 #set length
ov = 1#ceiling(len/2) # set overlap
b <- blocks(len, ov, length(vec))
#with(b, Map(function(i, j) vec[i:j], starts, ends))

out <- with(b, Map(function(i, j) vec[i:j], starts, ends))
last_1en <- length(out)
if(length(out[l1]) < len) { # if last length is less than set length
  out[[l1]] <- unlist(out[(ov) + (len - l1)])
}
out
```

> Error in out[[l1]] : subscript out of bounds

> [[1]]
> [1] 1 2 3 4 5

> [[2]]
> [1] 5 6 7 8 9

> [[3]]
> [1]  6  7  8  9 10

**Second Edit**

I have debugged the error by changing the `out[[l1]]` to `out[l1]`.

Comment: You can modify `b` with `b$starts[nrow(b)] <- b$ends[nrow(b)] - len + 1`

Comment: The required result doesn't satisfy your stated condition.

Comment: @norie can you point it out very well for me?

Comment: The overlap in the last sub-vector is 7, not 4.

Comment: @norie Yes, that is the modification I need to make so that I will have equal subvectors size

Comment: Why not modify so the overlap is still 4 and fill the rest of the sub vector with NA?

Comment: The equal subvectors size is very important to me, I can not trade it off

Comment: Please check my question for new edition, I have posted an attempt that comes with error message but nice solution.

Comment: changing `last_1en <- length(out)` to `l1 <- length(out)`  means it is used in your `if(length(` test and appears to work.

Comment: You can also try to change the first line of function `blocks` to `starts <- pmin(n-len+1, unique(sort(c(seq(1, n, len), seq(len-ov+1, n, len)))))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another way of modifying `blocks` function to achieve your desired output. Here is a little more details on how I wrote this function:

- For this purpose I used a structure called function factory which in fact is a function that creates another function
- If you pay attention I put the `len` argument in the outer most function cause I needed to set up my `out` vector first and aside from global environment
- After we first call `blocks` on defining `len` argument we will get to the second function where we specify `vec` and `ov` arguments
- Within the inner most function I used **recursion** to have the repetitive operation done by the function itself in much longer vectors
- Just a little more on recursion, it is a technique in programming where a function calls itself from inside of it's execution environment & If you notice each time I modify `vec` at the end of every operation and the new `vec` will be the input of the next `blocks` function running on the same `ov`
- So if we will call `blocks` like `blocks(len)(vec, ov)`
- In the end I took the indices and subset your vector, using the `Original_vector` this time to get to your desired output
  I know this approach may be a bit complicated but I think you can use it for your purpose just as much as other solutions.

```
# First I create a copy of our vector
Original_vector <- vec

# Then I rewrite `blocks` function in order to get the required indices
blocks <- function(len) {
  out <- c(1, len)
  
  fn <- function(vec, ov) {

    if(length(vec[-c(min(out):max(out))]) > ov) {
      out <<- c(out, c(out[length(out)] - (ov - 1), out[length(out)] + (len - ov)))
    } else {
      out <<- c(out, c(vec[length(vec)] - (len - 1), vec[length(vec)]))
      return(out)
    }
    out
    vec <<- vec[-c(min(out):max(out))]
    
    fn(vec, ov)
  }
  
}

result <- blocks(8)(1:17, 4)
> result
[1]  1  8  5 12  9 16 10 17
```

Then I use the acquired indices to subset my desired output

```
m <- as.data.frame(matrix(result, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
mapply(function(x, y) Original_vector[x:y], m$V1, m$V2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

[[2]]
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

[[3]]
[1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

[[4]]
[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

Answer (score 4):

A tidyverse strategy, I think should work properly for all kind of input vectors

```r
vec = 1:23
len = 7
ov = 6

library(tidyverse)
anil <- function(vec, len, ov){
  seq_len((length(vec) - ov) %/% (len - ov) +1) %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  setNames('id') %>%
  mutate(start = accumulate(id, ~ .x + len - ov),
         end = pmin(start + len - 1, length(vec)),
         start = pmin(start, end - len + 1)) %>%
  filter(!duplicated(paste(start, end, sep = '-'))) %>%
  transmute(desired = map2(start, end, ~ vec[.x:.y])) %>%
  as.list
}

anil(1:23, len = 7, ov = 6)
#> $desired
#> $desired[[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#> 
#> $desired[[2]]
#> [1] 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#> 
#> $desired[[3]]
#> [1] 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
#> 
#> $desired[[4]]
#> [1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
#> 
#> $desired[[5]]
#> [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
#> 
#> $desired[[6]]
#> [1]  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
#> 
#> $desired[[7]]
#> [1]  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
#> 
#> $desired[[8]]
#> [1]  8  9 10 11 12 13 14
#> 
#> $desired[[9]]
#> [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15
#> 
#> $desired[[10]]
#> [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
#> 
#> $desired[[11]]
#> [1] 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
#> 
#> $desired[[12]]
#> [1] 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
#> 
#> $desired[[13]]
#> [1] 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
#> 
#> $desired[[14]]
#> [1] 14 15 16 17 18 19 20
#> 
#> $desired[[15]]
#> [1] 15 16 17 18 19 20 21
#> 
#> $desired[[16]]
#> [1] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
#> 
#> $desired[[17]]
#> [1] 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
```

```
anil(LETTERS[1:21], 7, 2)
#> $desired
#> $desired[[1]]
#> [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "F" "G"
#> 
#> $desired[[2]]
#> [1] "F" "G" "H" "I" "J" "K" "L"
#> 
#> $desired[[3]]
#> [1] "K" "L" "M" "N" "O" "P" "Q"
#> 
#> $desired[[4]]
#> [1] "O" "P" "Q" "R" "S" "T" "U"
```

```
anil(1:17, 8, 4)
#> $desired
#> $desired[[1]]
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
#> 
#> $desired[[2]]
#> [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
#> 
#> $desired[[3]]
#> [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
#> 
#> $desired[[4]]
#> [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: Works in range of `ov = 3:7`, which is to say, quite well.

Comment: @Chris, why so?  I have not limited ov range?  See my edited answer, please

Comment: @Daniel-James doesn't commit to overlap being 1/2 length, just constant, at least as suggested prior to edits, but my caution was simply for future copy/pasters. As for letters, see ov =1.

Comment: @Chris, perhaps I am not able to get you correctly.  I think OP provided three inputs, ov, len and a vec and he wants an output list with 2 conditions.  Am I incorrect to perceive this completely?

Comment: You're completely correct, OP has revised his desires via edits. I'm just pointing out that all presented solutions are fragile as overlap trends below 3, which suggests his original head( might better have been tail(, for indexing.

Comment: @27ϕ9, thanks for pointing it out.  It was delivering duplicate when len-ov = 1.  Nevertheless, I used an extra step and nor created a function `anil` which, IMHO, is working well for all conditions.

Answer (score 1):

This will give the desired result but it's quite convoluted so I'm pretty sure there'll be a better solution out there.

```r
########Block function######################
blocks <- function(len, ov, n) {

  starts <- seq(1, n,len-ov)
  ends <- pmin(starts + len - 1, n)
  

  if(ends[length(starts)-1]-starts[length(starts)-1]+1 < len){
    ends[length(starts)-1] = n
    starts[length(starts)-1] = ends[length(starts)-1]-len+1
  }
  
  # truncate starts and ends to the first num elements
  num <- match(n, ends)
  head(data.frame(starts, ends), num)
}

########Moving block#############
vec = 1:17 # a list or vector
len = 8 # the length of the sublist or subvector 
ov = ceiling(len/2) # the length of overlap
b <- blocks(len, ov, length(vec))
b
with(b, Map(function(i, j) vec[i:j], starts, ends))
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not something more subtle?

```
len <- 8
ov <- ceiling(len / 2)

Map(`+`, list(1:len), as.list(c((ov*0:(ov - 1))[-ov], 17 - len)))
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
# 
# [[2]]
# [1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```

Comment: @AnilGoyal The examples do not indicate such a case.

Comment: The usefulness of this is in time series data and not necessarily be an integer. I use the 1,2,3,... just to monitor the performance of the result.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively easy way to calculate the end and start indices then iterate over the results to extract the subvectors:

```
blocks <- function(vec, len, ov) {
  end <- unique(c(seq(len, length(vec), len - ov), length(vec)))
  start <- end - len + 1
  Map(\(s, e) vec[s:e], start, end)
}

blocks(vec, len, ov)

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

[[2]]
[1]  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12

[[3]]
[1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16

[[4]]
[1] 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
```